# Jquery sidr stop content scrolling vertically

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, scroll

I have jQuery sidr set up for mobile devices on a site I am working on.

It all works fine but when you get to the middle of the mobile menu and you want to scroll down to the end of it, the body content scrolls as well and I would like to stop this.

This is my jquery:

```
//Mobile Menu
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#simple-menu').sidr({
      side: 'right'
  });
```

Also I should probably mention that I have had to put the following css at the end of my stylesheet (because on iPad safari I had a white line visible on the right hand side):

```
html,body{
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:hidden; 
  }
```

Comment: try giving a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: created a fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/2qBKK/) it might not be correct so please bear with me.